# Method of characteristic for a system of first order PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, hyperbolic-pde

I am working with this system of first order PDEs:

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
%Suscettibili 
&\frac{\partial{S}(a,t)}{\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial{S}(a,t)}{\partial{a}}= -\lambda(a,t)S(a,t)\\
%Infection detention: CIN0 - DNA POSITIVE
&\frac{\partial{I}(a,t)}{\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial{I}(a,t)}{\partial{a}}= \lambda(a,t)S(a,t)-{\eta}I(a,t)+rL(a,t)\\
%CIN1: persistence- clearance
%&\frac{\partial{P}(a,t)}{\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial{P}(a,t)}{\partial{a}}={\eta}I_{f}(a,t)-o(a)P(a,t)\\
&\frac{\partial{L}(a,t)}{\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial{L}(a,t)}{\partial{a}}= {\eta}I(a,t)-rL(a,t)\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

where $\eta$, $r$ are constant parameters and with conditions: 
$$S(0,t)=1,\quad S(a,0)=S^{0},\quad I(0,t)=0, \quad I(a,0)=I^{0}$$
$$\quad L(0,t)=0, \quad L(a,0)=L^{0}$$.

I want to solve it with the method of characteristic but actually I have no clue because it it a system. From the first equation, integrating along the characteristic line t-a = constant I get 
$$
S(a,t)=e^{-\int_{0}^{a}\lambda(t-a+\sigma,\sigma)d\sigma}
$$
But, then how can I procede for solving the other two equations? Any suggestions?

Comment: Adding the second and third equations allows to get $I+L=f$. After that substitute $L=f-I$ in the third equation.

Comment: There is no generally applicable method of characterstics for first order systems, as far as I know. After all, any PDE system could be reduced to a first order system by introducing more variables and equations. However, in your case, after a change of variables $a=s+b$, $t=s$, your PDE becomes an ODE in $s$ with a parameter $b$. I can't say in advance whether you'll find any "explicit solutions" this way, but at least the usual ODE theory (existence, uniqueness, continuous/smooth dependence on parameters) gives an abstract starting point.

Comment: Writing $D = \partial_t + \partial_a$, $X = (S, I, L)$, and $A$ the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix} - \lambda \\ \lambda & -\eta & r \\ & \eta & - r\end{pmatrix} $$ your equation is the _linear_ system of ODE (as Igor said) $$ DX = AX $$ where the matrix $A$ has variable coefficients. You can still explicitly integrate to get $X = X_0 \exp \int A$.